# Styling with QRadioButton and [type="..."]

Tags: qt, styles, wincc-oa

I'm using Qt for styling my radio buttons and use the program WinCC OA. The problem is when I use

```
QRadioButton::indicator::unchecked
```

all my radio buttons get this style. I want to give them different styles with types. But wherever I input my

```
[type="Radiobuttons_1"]
```

in the code above the style is not accepted and my radio button lose their style.

How can I style them differently?

Answer (score 1):

Within WinCC OA, you have to define the **TypeName** of the RadioButtons within the **Property** dialog of the corresponding UI element in the GEDI application, in your case to *"Radiobuttons_1"*.

Be aware that you can reload the stylesheets with **Edit > Reload Stylesheet**